# How to find out the version of installed VirtualBox platform packages?

Tags: virtualbox

I'm on macos Monterey and I cant verify whether the [Virtual Box Extension Pack](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Downloads) are installed or which version.

I've looked in the VirtualBox Manager's preferences and could not find it. Does the OS register what is installed?

Answer (score 1):

There is only one Virtual Box Extension pack for each version of VirtualBox. First, you need to determine which version of VirtualBox you have. Below is the image displayed when `VirtualBox`>`About VirtualBox` is selected from the menu bar on my Mac.

[image]

The version is 6.1.34. Next, goto the the proper webpage and select the correct VirtualBox Extension Pack to download. In my case, [this page](https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_6_1).

Finally, when I try to install the download, I get the following message, because the correct one is already installed.

[image]

Also, if you open VirtualBox and have the wrong Extension pack, you will get a message.

Comment: Sorry there was a mix-up. I meant the extension packages not VirtualBox itself. I did mention I am using macos Monterey, so I don't understand what you mean by "assuming your computer is a Mac...", is any Info other missing?

Comment: OK, I updated my answer.